# How do I connect my iPhone to the virtual machine (VMware macOS)?

Tags: iphone, xcode, virtual-machine, vmware, macos-sierra

my virtual machine (VMware macOS) doesn't see my iPhone when I connect my iPhone to the computer. Anyone knows how to handle this ? I want to connect just for using my iPhone as simulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your iPhone with the lightning connector would be perceived by VMWare as a USB Device, so you could refer to their [USB Device documentation](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws45/doc/devices_usb_ws.html).  The TL;DR is essentially:

1. Add the physical usb port to what the vm can "see".

   > Choose VM > Removable Devices to connect specific USB devices to your virtual machine.
2. Find the menu item for the usb port the iPhone is plugged into and mouse over it to see the iPhone, then click its name.

I found some additional instructions [here](https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1021853) which may provide more useful, granular details on how to do this.  Pleas note that you will have to take into account the OS of both the host and the guest when following the documentation.  Additionally, you may need specific drivers to let the guest addition recognize the iOS device.

Good luck!

Comment: @FurkanTopal If my answer solves your problem, please mark it as correct by clicking the green checkbox.  If not, please say why it didn't help or what happened when you tried what I suggested.  This will help others to figure out the correct solution.  Thanks!